# Why do I only have a subset of asp.net membership tables?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sql, membership-provider

**Summary:** 
I am trying to use asp.net membership, roles, and profiles, but am having trouble getting my code to use the tables generated by aspnet_regsql.exe.

**What I tried:**

1. Ran aspnet_regsql.exe on my database. This worked and all the tables were created.
2. Called `Membership.CreateUser("tester7","tester7","tester7@hi.com");`

This then created the following tables and stored the user in dbo.Memberships instead of dbo.aspnet_Memberships.

- dbo.Applications
- dbo.Memberships
- dbo.Profiles
- dbo.Roles
- dbo.Users
- dbo.UsersInRoles

It completely ignored the tables created by aspnet_regsql.exe.

Why is this happening and what can I do to target to aspnet_* tables?

**Edit to include Web.config Membership registration**

```
<membership defaultProvider="ProjectMembershipProvider">
  <providers>
    <add name="ProjectMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultMembershipProvider,..." connectionStringName="ProjectSql" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10" applicationName="Project" />
  </providers>
</membership>
```

Comment: What does your membership registration look like (web.config)?

Comment: @Forty-Two: I edited above to include my membership registration

Comment: Looks like you may have a previously implemented custom membership provider that is swooping in and 'stealing' your test user during registration.

Comment: Looks like that is precisely it. Candie's answer below gives my specific issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must add registering section in your config file

System.Web.Providers.DefaultMembershipProvider are on Sql Compact and Azur application

You have section for membership and another for role manager

```
<membership>

  <providers>

    <add

      name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider"

      type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider, ..."

      connectionStringName="LocalSqlServer"

      enablePasswordRetrieval="false"

      enablePasswordReset="true"

      requiresQuestionAndAnswer="true"

      applicationName="/"

      requiresUniqueEmail="false"

      passwordFormat="Hashed"

      maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5"

      minRequiredPasswordLength="7"

      minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="1"

      passwordAttemptWindow="10"

      passwordStrengthRegularExpression=""

    />

  </providers>

</membership>
```

Comment: Is this all happening simply because I used System.Web.Providers.DefaultMembershipProvider instead of System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider?

Comment: @Kiwi yes that's the reason of your problem

Comment: System.Web.Providers.DefaultMembershipProvider is with Sql Compact and Azur application

Comment: Thanks. I assume I will need to specify System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider and System.Web.Security.SqlProfileProvider in my profile and roleManager config sections, respectively, as well?

Comment: I'am happy to help you, yes you must specify two, membership in order to manage user, and rolemanager in order to manage role of user

Comment: Thanks very much. It's always something simple. Everything is in working order now.